# jQuery removeClass not working in IE

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

The mouseover on the menu is working fine in all browsers except IE8 and IE7:

```
$(function(){

    $(".menu ul li").hover(function(){

        $(this).addClass("hover");
        $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'visible');

    }, function(){

        $(this).removeClass("hover");
        $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'hidden');

    });

    $(".menu ul  li ul li:has(ul)").find("a:first").append(" &raquo; ");

});
```

Comment: Are you trying to build a multi-level menu? Can you add a sample of your HTML structure?

Comment: What version of jquery? jquery 2.0 removes support for old IE: http://blog.jquery.com/2012/06/28/jquery-core-version-1-9-and-beyond/

Answer (score -1):

jQuery 1.x will work with IE6+
jQuery 2.x will work with IE9+.
Check you jQuery and IE version. THis should solve your problem.